# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, navbar

[Here's a screenshot of the exact responsive navbar I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZfd7.png)  [A screenshot of the navbar on fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwr4Q.png) [A screenshot of the navbar on mobile size screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZiIy.jpg) I've been trying to get my responsive nav-bar/header to function properly, but the listed items on the header, seems to scatter around the page when I click the icon to show the menu when I'm in mobile sized screen.

To explain it a bit better, I want to do a navbar kinda like this: 
https://house.jumia.com.ng/. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color:#36b;
  color:#ffffff;
  border-radius:0;
  height:68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }
   
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:13px;
 }
   
 .btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: none !important;
 }

.first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color:#73ADFF;
  vertical-align:middle,!important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:600;
  margin-top:14px;
  margin-right:150px;
 }
```

```html
      
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                     
      </button>
    </div>
                                    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
          <a href="signup.php">
            <button class="btn first">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
          </span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="signup.php">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
            </span>&nbsp;Login / Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>              
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code and compared it towards the bootstrap documentation and you can see the difference: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-default

All your issues are CSS related. Also you did not post all of your code, the screen-shot you took is different from what code you posted here. Anyway I re-adjusted your CSS and got the mobile-menus to act properly on my machine. Review below:

```css
    .navbar-custom {
      background-color:#36b;
      color:#ffffff;
      border-radius:0;
      /*height:68px; Don't need to compensate for the large padding now*/
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    /* padding: 25px 0 75px 0; Not sure why so much padding */
    padding: 25px 0 5px 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-size:13px;
  }

   /*Make sure we can see our mobile menu on our blue background */
  .navbar-custom button.navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  .navbar-custom span.icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
    border-radius: 0.6em;
    color: #e74c3c;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: none !important;
  }

  .first {
    border-color: #73ADFF;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#73ADFF;
    vertical-align:middle,!important;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-top:14px;
    margin-right:150px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out mate

Comment: Compadre, I've tried your code, but it isn't giving me the exact result, the mobile menu on the the link is a small square box by the right, also the hamburger button is transparent.

Comment: Correct, the menu is on the right side. When I started with your html/css code the hamburger button was transparent. My CSS enables it to show. I took your EXACT html posted and added my css. Not sure what you aren't seeing. Also what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: It isn't transparent here padre, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7